# Palindrome problem code,i do get terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' in c++ error

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int palindromeMethod(string str)
{
    int max_val=str.size();
    bool result;
    for(int i=0;i<max_val;i++)
    {
        
        if(str.at(i)==str.at(max_val))
        {   if(i==max_val)
            {
                result=true;
            }
            max_val=max_val-1;
            
        }
        else
        {
            result=false;
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}

int main() {

string word="ROTOR";
bool result;
result=palindromeMethod(word);

if(result==true)
{
    cout << "Given String is palindrome";
}
else
{
    cout << "Given String is NOT palindrome";
}
}
```

This code i try to run  but  i am getting the  error  like  below

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 5) >= this->size() (which is 5)
Command terminated by signal 6

Comment: `str.at(max_val)` is accessing the string beyond the end on the first iteration.

Comment: Aside: `for(int i=0, j=str.size()-1;i<=j;i++,j--)` You can declare multiple variables in a `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

Two bugs in your code

```
int max_val=str.size();
bool result;
for(int i=0;i<max_val;i++)
{        
    if(str.at(i)==str.at(max_val))  //<-- exception here because index must be less than size() (starting from 0)
```

You can fix them by changing:

```
int max_val=str.size() - 1;  // instead of str.size()
```

and the loop index should also be `<=` :

```
for(int i=0;i <= max_val;i++) // instead of i < max_val
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a few bugs in your code. The one you are encountering now is this:

```
int max_val = str.size();
...
str.at(max_val)
```

Here you index one past the end of your string.

The next is that your loop condition clashes with one of the inner `if`s:

```
for (int i = 0;i < max_val;i++)
...
    if (i == max_val)
```

The loop stops when `i` becomes equal to `max_val`, so the `if` will never be true. @artm provides a possible solution for both of these in their answer.

The last bug, that I noticed, in your program is that you continue to loop through the string even after finding a non-matching character-pair. This means that while your program runs with @artm's fixes, it also reports "MOTOR" as a palindrome. You can fix this by returning `false` as soon as you find a mismatching pair - or if you insist on looping through the entire string, then initialize `bool result = true` and change your loop to something like:

```
    for (int i = 0;i <= max_val;i++)
    {
        result = result && (str.at(i) == str.at(max_val));
        max_val = max_val - 1;
    }
```